# C# - Being unable to implement "INotifyDataErrorInfo"

Tags: c#, interface, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have a c# class.

```
  class MyClass: AnotherClass, INotifyDataErrorInfo
  {
           ..................             
  }
```

I need to implement "INotifyDataErrorInfo" interface too. But it comes in Red Colour and does not identify the namespace of the interface.
I have added "using System.ComponentModel;" too.
But it does not work.

anyone knows why it is ?

[image]

Comment: What type of project are you developing? Is it a .NET 4.5-4.6 project? Please provide the full errormessage.

Comment: And have you added `System.ObjectModel.dll` to your referenced Dlls?

Answer (score 1):

[INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the namespace `System.ComponentModel` in the assembly `System`.  Make sure you have `using System.ComponentModel;` in your source code and the Project (.csproj) references the `System.dll`.

Comment: Well he did stated that he added the corresponding using directive. And IIRC `System.dll` is mostly included in every project, isn't it?

Comment: @ckruczek, yes mate and I don't believe OP.

Comment: Hahah ok, but I don't think this has to be an answer, though.